# Difference between n-channel MOSFET and p-channel MOSFET in a buck-boost converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

From TI's [Understanding Buck-Boost Power Stages in Switch Mode Power Supplies](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva059a/slva059a.pdf):

[image: buck-boost converter]

[image]

My question: why is a floating drive needed for an n-channel MOSFET but not for a p-channel MOSFET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a P-MOSFET the source is connected to the supply. This means that V<sub>G(off)</sub> is always less than the supply and therefore the transistor can be turned off easily.

With a N-MOSFET the source is connected to the *output*. This means that V<sub>G(on)</sub> is not only greater than the output (by definition), it may in fact be *greater than the supply*. This means that a special drive circuit may be required in order to turn the transistor on.