# Choosing the correct Gate Driver for a MOSFET in a DC-to-DC Converter

Tags: power, transistors, mosfet, pwm, switch-mode-power-supply

I am building my first simple buck converter, stepping down 12 V to 5 V and driving a small load of 5 Ω - 10 Ω. Something like the following:

[image]

or:

[image]

The above images both show an N-channel MOSFET. I am confused as to what would be the best option to drive the N-channel MOSFET at a 10 kHz switching frequency, keeping in mind the above parameters.

I have read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/257963/difference-between-n-channel-mosfet-and-p-channel-mosfet-in-a-buck-boost-convert), that for an N-channel MOSFET a special drive circuit may be required to turn the transistor ON, so a P-channel MOSFET may be easier to implement.

As for the gate-driver I have seen plenty, and a popular, cost-effective circuit seems to incorporate a non-inverting [totem-pole driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slua618/slua618.pdf) as shown.

[image]

I was thinking whether the above circuit would be good in my case, and simply give the PWM pulse at `Rb`.

**- What would be a suitable gate driving IC for an N-channel MOSFET, and why?**

**- IF a P-channel MOSFET is more suited for this application, then I would go for the least 'complex' solution and use a P-channel MOSFET. What would be a suitable P-channel drive circuit/IC?**

I have never designed something like this before, so please keep this in mind :) Any tips and/or suggestions would be appreciated!

---

**Edit:** Just for clarification.

1. Cost is not an issue in this case.
2. Simpler design (fewer parts) is better.

Comment: There are so many ICs that are well engineered for this kind of work, off the shelf. Why not use one of those?

Comment: This will be a part of a larger project I am planning, and simply would like to build most of it myself, from scratch.

Comment: I would [start here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva477b/slva477b.pdf) The frequency is rather low and a 1n4007 is a poor choice, too slow. Use a simulator to check your circuit.

Comment: Notice that the second diagram has the MOSFET connected on the low side of the load, where your first diagram has the FET on the high side of the load. To get good efficiency with the FET on the high side of the load, you'll need to be able to apply a gate voltage higher than VIN.

Comment: Which buck regulator ICs do with with a switched capacitor circuit. But for a from-scratch approach you might rather just use a p-channel FET.

Comment: @lakeweb, thanks for the good source. Will definitely use to calculate above component selection

Comment: @ThePhoton, thanks for your input on this. So you would suggest a p-channel FET due to the fact that a gate voltage higher than VIN must be applied for greater efficiency? Are there IC drivers that make this possible using an N_channel?

Comment: Yes, you can look for a high-side gate-driver IC. I don't know exactly what is available since I mainly work with integrated controller (or integrated regulator) ICs for this kind of application.

Comment: You have two obvious options here go for a P-channel FET since it is easier to drive, though depending on power level P-channel tends to be more expensive and less available.  Alternatively you need a 'high side' drive circuit.   This could use a gate drive transformer or an IC. My preference would be an IC.  They work by storing the energy needed to drive the gate in a capacitor.  It is used to power the gate when the transistor is on and gets charged when the diode is conducting.  The rules of this site do not let me make shopping suggestions but there are lots out there.

Comment: @WarrenHill, I assume that not *any* 'high side' drive circuit IC would work equally well. I am not looking for any shopping suggestions, simply if the one I pointed out would be suitable, and if not what should I look for in a 'high side' drive IC?

Comment: It is not clear what is the reason for this exercise. With 1 A load at 5 V and 10kHz switching, there is no difference whatsoever how to drive and which FET. Driving a high-side FET is a subject of fine IC engineering, which has a good budget of transistors to drive a FET in truly optimal way. The right way is to use a dedicated switcher IC with integrated FET, or a switching controller, which will drive the external FET properly. So, where is the beef? I see no value in this exercise, even educational. Looks more like a shopping question.

Comment: And what about the rest of the circuitry? Error amplifier? Voltage reference, PWM converter? Who will do all this stuff if you are unclear how to drive a high-side FET?

Comment: I will be using a fixed load, so no need for feedback circuitry. Also, I am applying a 10 kHz signal from a signal generator. As I said above, I am not asking for any shopping suggestions, simply, if an N-channel or P-channel FET would be optimal in this case and what type of driver would be preferred. (Bootstrap driver, synchronous driver, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply use a driver like [ADP3120](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/ADP3120AJRZ-RL/ADP3120AJRZ-RLOSCT-ND/3487284) or one of its cousins. This one drives 2 MOSFETs in synchronous rectification mode, which will be a bit more efficient than using a FET and a diode. Considering the low price of this driver, there is really no reason to build a complex circuit for this.

If you want to keep the diode, there are also high-side driver chips.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and suggestion. I am failing to understand why you say that I may remove the diode when using the driver you suggested. 

As far as I know in a buck converter, during the charge phase, the diode prevents the capacitor from discharging, while during the discharge phase, the inductor current continues to flow into the rectification diode to charge the output. Doesn't this mean that the diode is a necessary component for the correct functioning of this converter?

I may be missing your point completely, however, and going off on a tangent.

Comment: The chip I quoted is drives 2 FETs so the diode is replaced by a FET which has the same role as the diode but less voltage drop, hence less losses. I'm sure you could find high-side only drivers, but I cant' quote one off the top of my head.

Comment: Good! You can use the digikey search engine, "FET driver" category, select "high-side driver" for FET+diode or "high and low side" for 2 FETs.

Comment: I found the above suggestion you made extremely helpful. I have decided to go ahead with this kind of driver. I would like to confirm that an external bootstrap circuit needs to be built in conjunction with the above driver, to drive the high-side MOSFET. Can such modifications be found internally in similar drivers or would it be easier to simply a\dd these components externally? Thanks

Comment: Usually if you buy a chip labeled "high-side driver" it will require a bootstrap, which is a capacitor and a diode. Some chips include the diode internally. The capacitor is always external, of course. Can you add links to the chip you plan to use?

Comment: In all honesty, the driver you linked to (ADP3120) will do the job in my circuit. I think that the diode is included internally but I am not sure. The following sentence on page 5 of the datasheet confused me: "The bootstrap circuit uses a charge storage capacitor (CBST) and the internal (or an external) diode." Datsheet found here: http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/ADP3120A-D.PDF

Comment: It says a bit further "An external diode is required" so I presume the "internal diode" text is a mistake... when I used this driver I added the diode.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible solutions. What is the best way to travel from London to Paris? By car, train or plane? They all work but the cost and performance will be different. The same applies to your problem. If you are set on a high side switch, there are a number of different options. I will outline a few common approaches:

1. Use an isolated DC-DC power supply plus a standard low side gate driver, e.g. MCP1416, whose reference point is the source of the MOSFET. This solution is expensive and has a high parts count.
2. Use a pulse transformer. Simple. The duty cycle here is limited to < 50%.
3. Use a bootstrapped high-side buck driver or a half bridge driver, e.g. LM5109. This is one of the simplest means of driving a high side switch. The following diagram illustrates this approach. You can read more [here](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-6076.pdf). Just be aware that you need to charge the bootstrap capacitor at startup.

[image]

For a buck converter, you can also shift the MOSFET to the ground rail. This is known as a low side buck. With a low-side buck you can use a standard low side MOSFET driver, e.g. MCP1416, which is very simple. However, measuring the output voltage becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For the low power application your describing (~5W output power) and your demand for a simple design i would recommend just using a simple buck controller IC with integrated switch (some even have a integrated inductor/diode aswell). The only external components would be input and output caps, (diode and inductor) and in some cases (if output voltage is adjustable) a voltage divider in the feedback path. These ICs normally have comprehensive application notes which makes the choice of external componens more or less foolproof.